# Free array of void pointers in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, malloc, void

I'm implementing a min/max heap in C and am trying to do it in general, since I'll need it for a future project.

The idea is to use a 1D array of `void*` with a generic comparator, `int (*cmp) (void*,void*)`.

My structure looks like this:

```
typedef struct heap {
    size_t capacity;
    size_t size;
    int (*cmp)(void *, void *);
    void **data;
} Heap;
```

I malloc the space for `void **data` in a call to heapalloc:

```
Heap*
heapalloc(size_t capacity, int (*cmp)( void *,  void *))
{
    Heap* h = malloc(sizeof(Heap*));
    if (h == NULL) 
    {
        perror("heapalloc/h:");
        return h;
    }

h->cmp = cmp;
h->data = malloc(capacity * sizeof(void*) );

if (h->data == NULL)
{
    perror("heapalloc/h->data:");
    free(h);
    return NULL;
}

h->size = 0;
h->capacity = capacity;
return h;
```

}

Everything is running fine, until I have to free data. The following call gives a seg fault, and I don't understand why---I've only called malloc once, and data is the pointer returned from it!

```
void
heapfree(Heap *h)
{ 
    free(h->data);
    free(h);
}
```

Any help would be appreciated. I've seen a lot of posts on similar topics, but nothing I've found has actually worked so far. (Compiling with gcc; hence sizeof(void*))

Comment: If you have only called `malloc` once, then why are calling `free` twice?

Comment: I should specify, that I'm only calling free once on h->data; after that is freed, I want to free the heap structure as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Heap* h = malloc(sizeof(Heap*));
```

is wrong; you want

```
Heap *h = malloc(sizeof *h);
```

Comment: that's bad style and you have to put the type in parentheses

Comment: This runs cleanly---thanks! 
Now, C isn't my strong suit---why does this even compile? The heap *h isn't initialized when you use it in sizeof(*h).

Comment: The compiler knows the sizeof(*h). It's clearer when one writes sizeof(Heap), but arguably less error prone when alloc'ing the size of the thing being assigned; a trivial difference in style in my opinion.

Comment: `sizeof` is an operator and does not require its operand to be initialized.  C standard says that its result is "... determined from the type of the operand"

Comment: @modulus0 It compiles because malloc doesn't do any size checking, and there's an implicit cast from the type `void*` (the return type of malloc) hidden in there. All of your writes to that struct, outside of `sizeof(Heap*)` bytes are technically corrupting data, which is likely why the segfault occurs. You may have been able to track this error down using a tool like valgrind's memcheck.

Comment: @modulus0 the reason that `sizeof *h` works is that the compiler does not figure out how much memory in the heap `h` points to, it figures out the size of the data type (struct) that `*h` represents.